# Firebase / angularFire2 v5 authentication issue on mobile

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am creating a PWA and trying to use firebase/angularfire2 v5 to authenticate my users against Facebook or Google (I followed a tutorial that is present in angularfire2 github site).
When I use the application in a "normal" browser in a desktop or mobile device everything works fine. 
The problem starts when I install the application in a mobile device and try to use the authentication (in the manifest.json the property display is set to "standalone"). I end up in a blank page. I tried to solve this using both ways to authenticate: popup and redirect. Both have the same issue.

Am I missing any configuration? Did you face similar issues? How did you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to this Chrome bug which affects standalone PWAs: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=771418

Comment: Good news, fixed in Chrome Canary https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=771418#c84

Comment: Cool, this is great news!